# How to know no of days left to receive unsung hero

Tags: feature-request, badges, zero-score-badges

I am able to calculate my unsung hero badge progress from this https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/66537/how-unsung-am-i but, I am unable to how many days left for me to receive that badge. I have already received Tenacious.

Comment: What do you mean "days left"? What do days have to do with it?

Comment: I was eligible to receive unsung hero, I know it will take 10 days to receive badge, I was querying from the above URl from the past 10 days and I found I am eligible to receive unsung hero hero, so I would like to know how many days do I need to wait..? is 10 days completed or not

Comment: Any specific answers you want upvoted? :-)

Comment: Here is a working query https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1228150/how-unsung-am-i-fixed-ver-includes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The one thing that the query you linked *doesn't* take into account is that only accepted answers ***at least 10 days old*** are considered for the badge, so that query is actually inaccurate. You probably don't yet qualify for the gold badge, and thus have not received it.

Data Exchange also uses *old data*. Currently it's querying data from March 5th.

Looking through your accepted answers, here are your current stats:

```
Accepted Answers        44
Zero-Score Accepted     9
Percentage              20.5%
```

Comment: Check my comment below question..

Comment: @Pragnani: If you were eligible for the badge, you would have been awarded it within 24 hours. The fact that you don't have it simply means you're not currently eligible.

Comment: What about the statistics from the past 10 days, I have searched my self in the SO search something like is:answer isaccepted:1 votes:0 like this...more than 10 answer and 25% of answers and not self accepted

Comment: Or, How do I query based on the date i.e I would like to know how many accepted answer, how many zero votes 10 days ago

Comment: @Pragnani: I've looked at your accepted answers and added your current stats to my answer.

Comment: is it days ago..Thanks..please provide me query to check my self.

Comment: @animuson - Are given data in your answer from Data.SE or real time?

Comment: You can use `user:me isaccepted:1` to find all your accepted answers, count how many are not at least 10 days old, and subtract from the total at the top. Then use `user:me isaccepted:1 votes:0` to find the number of zero-scored accepted and repeat.

Comment: @hims056: I used basic search commands and counted.

Comment: But [user:1727092 isaccepted:1](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A1727092+isaccepted%3A1) showing 67 accepted answers. and [user:1727092 is:answer isaccepted:yes score:0](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a1727092%20is%3aanswer%20isaccepted%3ayes%20score%3a0) showing 19 answers??? Am I missing something?

Comment: @animuson Gasp! Manually?! ;)

Comment: @hims056: You have to exclude the ones that aren't 10 days old, which is February 25 at approximately 07:00 UTC (now).

Comment: @animuson - Ohh got it.

Comment: @animuson i Have got my badge today, Actuallly it was 10 days but because of Time zome....any how thanks

Comment: @Pragnani: It's because a bunch of your zero-scored accepted answers just became eligible for the badge today (the ones from February 26), which put your stats over the required threshold.